# JSF component is not rendered from my p:commandButton in in a dialog in included page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, conditional-rendering, ajax-update

My page contains a login header that i include via ui:include. The included page contains a dialog with a p:commandButton. When the user logs in, the include page is refreshed properly according to the @form in the update attribute. I also want to update a component outside the included page, that shall display a button when the user is logged in. The include page refreshes and the name of the logged in user is displayed. But the button in the main page is not shown. It is displayed if I refresh the page though. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Anyone have any ideas.

The header page also displays the commandLink component properly. But when clicking the logout link, the button in the main page is not removed. Since the commandLink does not use ajax, I assume that a normal page POST is done. Which should reload the whole page. Doesn't this work from a page that have been referenced with ui:include?

The login page is using a session scoped backing bean. The main page is view scoped.

Here's the included xhtml (login.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <div style="width:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;background-color:#b0d9e6;color:white">

<h:form>
<h:message id="top_msg"></h:message>
    <h:panelGrid width="100%" columns="3" columnClasses="none,right1,right1">
       <h:outputLink rendered="#{!loginController.loggedIn}" styleClass="text-align:right;" value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" title="login">
             <p:outputLabel>Login</p:outputLabel>
        </h:outputLink>


    <h:commandLink rendered="#{loginController.loggedIn}" action="#{loginController.logout}" styleClass="text-align:right;" >
         <h:outputLabel>Logout</h:outputLabel>
    </h:commandLink>

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

    <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{loginController.username}" required="true" label="username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{loginController.password}" required="true" label="password" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" 
                        update="@form :createform:createbutton"
                        actionListener="#{loginController.login}"
                        oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" >

                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
    </h:panelGrid>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)


</script>

</h:form>

</div>

</ui:composition>
...
```

This one is included in the following main page:

```
...
<ui:include src="login.xhtml" />

   <h:form id="createform">
   <h:panelGroup id="createbutton" layout="block">

     <p:commandButton id="createnew"
        ajax="false" 
        action="#{recepieController.createNewRecipes}" 
        value="Create new recipe" 
        rendered="#{recepieController.loggedIn and !recepieController.create and !recepieController.viewOnly and !recepieController.edit}"
        accesskey="s">
      </p:commandButton>
 </h:panelGroup>     
  </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In my commandButton "createnew", I used the wrong value to render on.

```
 <p:commandButton id="createnew"
    ajax="false" 
    action="#{recepieController.createNewRecipes}" 
    value="Create new recipe" 
    rendered="#{recepieController.loggedIn and !recepieController.create and !recepieController.viewOnly and !recepieController.edit}"
    accesskey="s">
  </p:commandButton>
```

It should use my session scoped bean (loginController) to check if the user is logged in. Changing to the following works.

```
  <h:panelGroup id="createbutton">
     <p:commandButton id="createnew"
        ajax="false" 
        action="#{recepieController.createNewRecipes}" 
        value="Create new recipe" 
        rendered="#{loginController.loggedIn and !recepieController.create and !recepieController.viewOnly and !recepieController.edit}"
        accesskey="s">
      </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

Note the difference **rendered="#{loginController.login ...}** instead of rendered="#{recepieController.loggedIn}"

The recepieController also has a loggedIn attribute which I set, but since the page is not re-posted I guess the value is not changed for the attribute when I login.
However, I believe I tested to use ajax="false" in the p:commandButton for the login dialog which I guess should reset the view scoped version of my loggedIn attribute. I don't fully understand why that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rerender a non-rendered component. If you partially render a button, and the button is not rendered, you cannot call an update on that button, because it does not exist in the DOM.

You have to call the AJAX update on the parent naming container, that is ALWAYS rendered. Thus, update the **:createform** rather than the button inside. The form is always rendered, no matter what.

Comment: Hello Kevkodez. Thanks for the answer. However I am referencing a rendered component. The panelGroup called createbutton is always rendered. It must be something else.